# Fix for iOS app otool cryptid=0

Tags: ios, otool

Hi recently I wrote an app for my company but later i found out this tool - otool. So i tried to check my app with otool and found the following:

```
 cmd LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO
      cmdsize 20
    cryptoff  4093
    cryptsize 142512
    cryptid   0
```

I googled the cryptid and learned that my app is not encrypted and can be cracked and RE. Does anyone knows how to fix it or how to set cryptid=1? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you release an app via the Apple App Store using iTunes Connect, it automatically gets encrypted with no input by the developer.  If you provisioned it locally via xCode it will not be encrypted.

That said, Apple's app encryption alone is only a thin security control.

This encryption can be removed.  Refer to `Clutch`.
Then the class headers can be dumped.  Refer to `Class-dump`.

With this information the reverse engineer  has enough start running more interesting run-time tools against your app.  Refer to `Frida`, `Cycript` or `LD_Preload` for some excellent examples.